# I can´t return the date and footer functions on flask

Tags: python, html, function, flask

> im a beginner, take that in cosideration, so, i need to pass the the footer and date functions and i somehow missing the point here

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from datetime import datetime


app = Flask("Timer Workout")



@app.route("/")
def Landing():
    return render_template("Landing_Page.html")

def footer():
    footerdb = open("footer.txt")
    for i in range (3):
        footerdb.write("footer.txt" + " by Carlos ")
    footerdb.close()
    return render_template("Landing_Page.html", footerdb)
```

The same here,i can´t return the date function, i don´t know exactly what should i do. Help appreciated. Thanks a lot.

```
    @app.route("/index.html/")
def Home():
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    return render_template("index.html", current_time = current_time)





if "Timer Workout" == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "pass the function"?

Comment: rdas sorry, return it.

Answer (score 2):

The function is not returning anything because it is not called.

Where do you want the date/time to be returned ?

If it's in /index.html you should do something like that :

```
@app.route("/index.html/")
def Home():
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    return render_template("index.html", current_time=current_time)
```

And then in your template you can add the variable inside your HTML code like that for example:

```
Current Date and Time: {{ current_time }}}
```

Basically you can define variables values inside your python main script. Pass them as arguments to the render_template function and then use them inside your template with `{{ your_var }}`.

Have a look here : https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, really appreciate.

Comment: But when i try this, it doesn´t open the index and the footer doesn´t return as a function.

Comment: im sure it´s a beginner mistake of syntax, i will show you

Comment: ``` @app.route("/")
def Landing():
    return render_template("Landing_Page.html")
    
def footer():
    footerdb = open("footer.txt")
    for i in range (3):
        footerdb.write("footer.txt" + " by Carlos Teixeira")
    footerdb.close()
    return render_template("Landing_Page.html", footerdb)```

Comment: @app.route("/index.html/")
def Home():
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    return render_template("/index.html/", current_time=current_time)

Comment: HTML:        <p class="footer">footer()</p> <a target="blank"></a></p>

Comment: AND : <p class="footer">Current Date and Time: {{ current_time }}}</p> <a target="blank"></a></p>

Comment: You are routing two different views, one is to yourwebsite.com/ with the function Landing() and the other is to yourwebsite.com/index.html with the function Home(). Based on what you gave me you are defining current_time inside Home() returning the 'index.html' template. So you should be able to call it inside the 'index.html' template with {{ current_time }} and see the result on yourwebsite.com/index.html.

Comment: On the other hand, I can't really understand your function for yourwebsite.com/ called 'Landing'.

Comment: You must define a variable inside the view function (Home() or Landing()) and then pass it as an argument of the returned render_template() function. Then you can access it ONLY in that rendered template. For example in your case you can access to 'current_time' in 'index.html' and not in 'landing_page.html'. for that you'll need to define this variable inside your Landing() function too. Notice the syntax of your Home() syntax which is fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214496/discussion-between-teixeira66-and-pablo).

Comment: I Rephrased, see if this time i undertand

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have time either but I can look into it now.
I think you are lost because you have two views with two different templates. And I guess, as for now, you only want to render one page.

So now your project should look like that:

Your `mainscript.py` is:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask("Timer Workout")

@app.route("/")
def Landing():
    return render_template("Landing_Page.html")

def footer():
    footerdb = open("footer.txt")
    for i in range (3):
        footerdb.write("footer.txt" + " by Carlos ")
    footerdb.close()
    return render_template("Landing_Page.html", footerdb)

@app.route("/index.html/")
def Home():
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    return render_template("index.html", current_time = current_time)

if "Timer Workout" == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

And then you should have two HTML files, `Landing_page.html` and `index.html`.

But, I think you are trying to render one and only one page with your footer and the current date and time.

For that I'll give you an example that should work. Just delete your `footer()` function which is buggy and not called anywhere and we'll make only one routing to render one template.

In your `mainscript.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from datetime import datetime


app = Flask("Timer Workout")

@app.route("/")
def home():
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    footer = "Placeholder string just for debugging"
    return render_template("index.html", current_time = current_time, footer = footer)


if "Timer Workout" == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Then in your `index.html` file put something like that:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index page</title>
</head>

<body>
Current date/time is : {{ current_time }}
<br><br>
The footer would be just below : <br>
{{ footer }}
</body>
</html>
```

Now when you access to `yourwebsite.com/` you'll see `index.html` properly rendered.
Of course then you should find a better way to add the footer, you will look into template inheritance with the `extends` tag. But for now try my example to understand the basics that should work easily.

Comment: ok thanks. But i actually want two render two files, the landing page with several functions including on with the footer that changes which time with the datafile that i have, and then the index page in which i have a timer workout with the datetime module running on the page